# I need a type of group-sort that I couldn't figure out with ROW_NUMBER on T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, row-number

I have a table with a table_id row and 2 other rows. I want type of numbering with row_number function and I want result to seem like this:

```
id   |col1 |col2  |what I want  
------------------------------
1    |x    |a     |1  
2    |x    |b     |2  
3    |x    |a     |3  
4    |x    |a     |3  
5    |x    |c     |4  
6    |x    |c     |4  
7    |x    |c     |4
```

please consider that;

- there's only one x, so "`partition by col1`" is OK. other than that;
- there are two sequences of a's, and they'll be counted seperately
- (not 1,2,1,1,3,3,3). and sorting must be by id, not by col2 (so
  `order by col2` is NOT OK).

I want that number to increase by one anytime col2 changes compared to previous line.

`row_number () over (partition by col1 order by col2)` DOESN'T WORK. because I want it ordered by id.

Answer (score 2):

Using `LAG` and a windowed `COUNT` appears to get you what you are after:

```
WITH Previous AS(
    SELECT V.id,
           V.col1,
           V.col2,
           V.[What I want],
           LAG(V.Col2,1,V.Col2) OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS PrevCol2
    FROM (VALUES(1,'x','a',1),  
                (2,'x','b',2),  
                (3,'x','a',3),  
                (4,'x','a',3),  
                (5,'x','c',4),  
                (6,'x','c',4),  
                (7,'x','c',4))V(id, col1, col2, [What I want]))
SELECT P.id,
       P.col1,
       P.col2,
       P.[What I want],
       COUNT(CASE P.Col2 WHEN P.PrevCol2 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY P.ID ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) +1 AS [What you get]
FROM Previous P;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ada4e71e2ee989e00cb533f9ae480440)

Comment: "ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW"

I didn't know we could directly talk to SQL :)
I'm trying, thanks in advance.

Comment: `ROWS BETWEEN` was added way back in SQL Server 2012, @balcis and is very useful for calculating things like running totals.

Comment: EDIT: The problem here is, your code works, OK. But I'm actually after handling this without creating another table but as it seems it's not possible. 
 When I'm trying to create P.PrevCol2 with a lag function (on the same line), I get the error:  `Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.`
  
My code is (to sample):
`select P.Col1
 , COUNT(case P.Col2 when 
  LAG(P.Col2) over (partition by P.Col1 order by P.id) then null else 1 end) 
  over (ORDER BY P.id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) +1 'wha?'
from TABLE P`

Comment: @balcis Where are you creating another table? I'm not in my example.

Comment: If you mean the `VALUES` construct, you would replace that entire with *your* table; I only use `VALUES` as I don't have access to your instance, so I need create the data somewhere. Technically speaking, as a result, i don't create any tables in the above, physical or temporary. As the error tells you though, you can't put `LAG` inside another aggregate, and why you need to define the value in the CTE (or a subquery) first.

Comment: `LAG` can't be inside the other aggregate funciton, @balcis ; that's why I define it in the expression prior.

Comment: you are right, you are not creating any tables, sorry, my mistake. I mean I need to handle it with one select without the need of much performance. It's a big table. and query must be simple.

Comment: You *must* use a CTE or subquery @balcis .